# Solution design for logging in UI layer

Tags: logging, architecture, three-tier

I have standard 3 tier (physical) infrastructure architecture -

1. UI Layer (ASP.NET MVC)
2. WebServices Layer (WCF Services)
3. DB Layer (SQL Server).

All the logging should be done in database using Log4net/EnterpriseLib. There is no direct connection possible between the UI tier and DB tier (because of firewall restrictions) . There is no problem in implementing logging in the "Web Services" layer but I would like ideas to implement logging in the UI layer.

Various options -

a) Implement all UI logging calls via webservices (drawback - performance overhead). Would it be recommended to make async webservice calls in this scenario ?

b) Implement all UI logging calls to store in an intermediate queue in the same machine and run a separate process to transfer the logs to the database.

Please suggest.

I would appreciate if anybody can share his/her real life project experience on this scenario.

Comment: Why not to allow UI to access db directly?

Comment: firewall restriction because of security reasons....

Comment: Yeah, what kind of security reasons? don't you trust your own application? Normally UI has access to a database so you must have specific security requirements.